# Regex for finding a snippet until the first underscore in parent folder

Tags: regex

I have a few folders that look like this:

```
A:\blah\folder\subfolders\0126535_whatever\file.ext
A:\blah\anotherfolder\subfolders\03578422_whatever\file.ext 
A:\blah\folder_with_underscore\subfolders\2175421_whatever\1342121_214561_file_with_underscore.ext
```

I was looking for a regex that would allow me to get only the "0126535"/"03578422" portions from the parent folder path, and not any of the other numbers.

Comment: As I see you need to capture 7-8 digit numbers, you can use this regex for it : `\d{7,8}`

Comment: Updated my question a bit (the paths are just example), I can't really rely on the parent folder numbers having a predictable number of digits, and the filenames might also have numbers with underscores.

Comment: From which path are you trying to extract the snippet?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/doslmx/1) what you want? If not, edit your question and add more test cases with **expected result**.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will do the trick `A:\\.*\\(\d+)_` (this is pcre2 by the way).

`A:\\`: This part matches "A:"
`.*`: This part matches everything up until..
`\\(\d+)_`: This is the meat of it. It will only match when there is a backslash followed by one or more numbers (which it will save) followed by an underscore.

Tell me if this doesn't work.